# What exception to throw when parsing a byte array? (C#)

Tags: c#, exception, arrays

I'm parsing a byte array, which is in effect a fix length record that is being sent on a message bus. If the data isn't valid (garbled or doesn't fit the spec for the record) then I want to throw an exception. Something like this:

```
public DomainObject ParseTheMessage(byte[] payload){
    Validate(payload);//throws an exception if invalid

    ...do creation of domain object
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a good standard exception I can throw in these circumstances or should I just create my own specific exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx):

```
throw new ArgumentException("payload", "'payload' should be...");
```

As mentioned below by x0r, [MSDN recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5tckx.aspx) only deriving from `ArgumentException`, doing so may or may not give you any added value, this depends on what defines an 'invalid' argument passed through the parameter - if you can define strict rules of what can go wrong, then you may well benefit from creating more precisely named exceptions that derive from `ArgumentException`.

Or, you could use [`InvalidDataException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.invaliddataexception.aspx) with the same kind of informative message, if you have one:

> The exception that is thrown when a data stream is in an invalid format.

Although referring to a data stream, there *might* be some objections - let's see.

If it is simply for a general 'bad format' exception, then you do have [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx) - but that might be *faaar* too general for your circumstance (see above), though maybe a far better exception to derive from, it really does depend:

> The exception that is thrown when the format of an argument does not meet the parameter specifications of the invoked method.

Comment: for the ArgumentException the doc says that you should only derive from it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5tckx.aspx

Comment: Then he could derive from it and name it `ArgumentInvalidFormatException`, but the name doesn't give it much more credibility that a useful `message`, unless the OP has some more specific cases that define an 'invalid' argument.

Comment: That sounds it might be a better fit. I'll have a think about that. Thanks. (The InvalidDataException that is...). Got to love stack overflow by the way. Good responses within seconds of asking.

Answer (score 2):

You may throw an ArgumentException with a custom InnerException.

Comment: Yes, I'm kind of wavering towards that but for various reasons it doesn't fit well (the code I gave is just a very basic version of what is happening). I was kind of hoping for an InvalidFormatException or something but I suspect it's either going to be an ArgumentException or something custom.

Answer (score 2):

If data validity criterion is application-specific and doesn't match any general case (like index out of range etc.), I think it is better to use your own exception. For standard case use existing exception, for example, NullPointerException if payload == null.

Answer (score 0):

[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx):

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown when a method is invoked and at
>   least one of the arguments passed to the method is not null and does
>   not contain a valid value.

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("payload","description of the specific problem");
```